# Can automation service to get the parent folder path?

Tags: macos, automator, script, automation, services

I already have a service that will create a network file:/// link to a share point over AFP but I would like to have one that does the parent folder of a file.

If I right click a file I would like to have the option to either choose to copy the file path to the file or the files parent folder.

I would prefer that the script be in Shell / bash and not in AppleScript and my dream scenario would be a way to copy both the file path and file path parent folder to the clipboard. Then when I pasted it would look like this:

File Path:
file:///Volume/parentfolder/file.pdf
Parent Folder:
file:///Volume/parentfolder

Preferably I would like to obtain four lines of text in the clipboard in one action, but the second half (parent folder) is the one I lack currently.

Comment: @bmike, I fail to see how you interpreted the OP to where you changed the last paragraph to include "Preferably I would like to obtain four lines of text in the clipboard in one action" when what I see shown is one line of text, i.e. `File Path: file:///Volume/parentfolder/file.pdf Parent Folder: file:///Volume/parentfolder`, so am I missing something or have you misinterpreted something? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I may have done a bad edit @user3439894 - can you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new **Automator Service**, with the following settings:

- **Service receives selected [files or folders] in [Finder]**

Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*, with the following settings:

- **Shell [/bin/bash]**               **Pass input [as argument]**

Replacing all of the *default code* with the *example code* below:

```
toTheClipboard="File Path: file://$(sed 's: :%20:g' <<< "$1") Parent Folder: file://$(dirname "$1" | sed 's: :%20:g')"
pbcopy<<<"$toTheClipboard"
```

Save the **Automator Service**, then in **Finder**, select an *item* and right-click selecting the *service* from the **Services** *context menu*. The *service* is also available from the **Finder** > **Services** menu.

You can then paste from the clipboard to wherever you want it.

---

**Note:** The *example code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: This is perfect except I would need the spaces to be replaced with %20 so they can be correctly linked. Im going to try some digging to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I tried but ive been unsuccessful in trying to remove the spaces in the text generated with %20. I would really appreciate an update to the code you provided without the spaces. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Brave_Buffalo, I've updated it to replace spaces with %20.