# Replace spaces in this shell script with %20

Tags: automator, spaces

I have this command from the question [Can automation service to get the parent folder path?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317097/can-automation-service-to-get-the-parent-folder-path) but it has spaces in it.

When it's ran it looks like this:

```
File Path: file:///Volumes/Desktop/Fortigate/Fortigate 200D/Policies.txt
Parent Folder: file:///Volumes/Desktop/Fortigate/Fortigate 200D
```

This is exactly what I wanted except that it has spaces and it needs to have %20 instead of the spaces in the file path.

Could someone show me how I would edit the shell script below to replace these spaces with %20?

```
toTheClipboard="File Path: file://$1 Parent Folder: file://$(dirname "$1")" pbcopy<<<"$toTheClipboard"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe to `sed 's/ /%20/g'` to replace spaces with %20.

```
toTheClipboard="File Path: file://$(echo $1 | sed 's/ /%20/g') Parent Folder: file://$(dirname "$1" | sed 's/ /%20/g')" pbcopy<<<"$toTheClipboard"
```

Comment: This was perfect... You saved my life today!